# Dual boot + isolate

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot set up for Windows 7 and Windows 8 which are both installed on the same hard drive but in two separate partitions. My Windows 7 machine has unrecognized software which may contain malware. I would therefore want to prevent Windows 7 from being able to access my main OS partition (Windows 8).

Will this setup protect my Windows 8 install from getting infected by a potential malware on my Windows 7 install?

Comment: I really don't understand why all the down-votes and close request. This is a legitimate question with a objective answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I'm having a hard time finding the question.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I thought it was clear, I edited the OP's question. OP: If I was wrong in what I typed please feel free to change what I added.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I don't understand the whole "My Windows 7 will endure unrecognised software" aspect. So, the Windows 7 installation *can* get infected and that would be fine for the OP? That sounds counter-intuitive and as if it would be a problem in itself. To me, it sounded like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you're going to regularly run "unrecognised software which may contain malware", why not do so inside a VirtualBox/Virtual PC/Hyper-V VM instead?

Answer (score 3):

Not having any partitions that windows 8 can access mapped to drive letters will stop 99% of all malware, but you will need to do it in the other direction too, so windows 8 can't see win7 partitions too. Otherwise a file that both systems can see will get infected on the 7 side, then you reboot, open the file on 8, and get infected over there too.

You may be better off just giving 8 the entire drive and running 7 inside a VM, that will help keep the separation of the two and you won't get any accidental spill over contamination.

Comment: How would I go about doing your first option. I already have VM and I'm not fond of its performance, nor the idea that I'm running two OS's just to get access to one.

Comment: In each OS just go to [Disk Management](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsd/p/disk-management.htm) (Right click `My Computer` and go to `Manage`) and you can remove the drive letters from the partition you do not want to see.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that [NeoGrub](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/NeoGrub) can do this as it can hide partitions (prevent accesses).

> NeoGrub has infinite number of possible usages - the sky truly is the
>   limit thanks to the scriptable boot process and chainloading support.
>   However, here are a couple of really cool things NeoGrub is often used
>   for:
>
> - Installing, configuring, and maintaining the GRUB bootloader from
>     within Windows -  no Live CDs, Super Grub Disks, or Linux
>     installations required.
> - Hiding partitions from one-another at boot time
> - Faking primary/active partitions.
> - Chainloading other Linux bootloaders such as GRUB2, LILO, and more.